# aws lambda: how to avoid creating version of lambda for each deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, version

I have a lambda version with huge dependencies. So, each time when the lambda deploys it is creating a new version which leads to storage issue.

I am using terraform to deploy the lambda. When I search the documentation only suggestion is to create a custom cloud watch trigger to call a separate lambda to delete the version.

Is there any option to avoid version creation of lambda using terraform

Comment: Have you considered using Lambda layers for dependencies?

Comment: What storage limit are you referring to? "Storage for uploaded functions (.zip file archives) and layers" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html?

Comment: I'm not good with Terraform but it looks like `publish = false` will do that for you. https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest#simple-deployments